# Is it possible to find the imported classes with the current JavaDoc APIs?

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet

I've been working on a custom Javadoc doclet using the current doclet APIs. Having encountered a `ReferenceTree` for a link, let's say `jdk.javadoc.doclet.Doclet#init(Locale, Reporter)`, I need to work out what classes `Locale` and `Reporter` correspond to. I can search in `jdk.javadoc.doclet` for `Reporter` and find it. But in order to find `Locale` I need to know that `java.util.Locale` was imported and I can't for the life of me work out how.

I even resorted to digging through the source for the standard doclet, but that's full of code that uses APIs that aren't exposed.

Can this be done using the public APIs?

I mean, I suppose I can search through all the classes in all the packages in all the modules in the `DocletEnvironment`, but if I don't find a unique answer, it'll be unclear how to decide which answer is correct if I can't find out what was imported.